# How to create a component named Tail that takes a number and renders the last N children

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning about children in react.js and am working on some exercises. The title is taken directly from what is being asked.
The topic is using children to display child components but only display certain child components.
I don't understand how this component can take a 'number' instead of using 'children' as the keyword.

I've tried using 'number' in the arguments for the Tail function but this doesn't give me the children. If I replace with children it works.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function Parent() {

    return (      

       <Head >
           <span>1</span>
           <span>2</span>
           <span>3</span>
           <span>4</span>
           <span>5</span>
           <span>6</span>
           <span>7</span>
       </Head> 

    )
}


function FirstChildOnly({ children }) { 
    let items = React.Children.toArray(children); 

return ( 
<div>{items[0]}</div> 
        );
}

function LastChildOnly({children}) {
    let items = React.Children.toArray(children);

return (
<div>{items[2]}</div>
        );
}

function Head({children}){

return (
<div>{React.Children.map(children, (child, i) => {
        if (i > 2) return
        return child
                })}
    </div>

        )
    }

    //use number instead of children here
function Tail({children}){
    let items = React.Children.toArray(children);

return(
<div>{}</div>
    )
}
```

The expected result is to write a component named Tail that takes a number and renders the last N children.

To give you more context the previous questions ask to: create a component called Head that takes a number prop and renders the first [number] children. e.g. If you pass number=3, and 7 child elements, it will render the first 3.

Update: The question suggests using React.Children.toArray(), I have tried this but still don't understand why 'number' or where 'number' is to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just use `toArray` on children and then use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method on Array. e.g:

```
function Tail({children, count}){
    return React.Children.toArray(children).slice(-count);
}
```

Remember to add `-` before count to return count from the end of the array.

You'd use it like so:

```
  <Tail count={2}>
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
  </Tail>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know I think your implementation for the functional component Head is incorrect, try this:

```
function Head(props){
    console.log(`Number: ${JSON.stringify(props.number)}`);
    console.log(`Children: ${JSON.stringify(props.children)}`);
    let childrenArray = React.Children.toArray(props.children);
    if(props.number > childrenArray.length){
      return <p>There only exists {childrenArray.length} elements, not {props.number}</p>
    }
    let result = childrenArray.splice(0, props.number);
    return (
      <div id="component-container">
        {result}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Now when we pass in the props, number=x and children, we will only render the 1st x children.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Head number={5}>
    <p>hey</p>
    <p>ma</p>
    <p>whats</p>
    <p>up</p>
    <p>you</p>
    <p>good</p>
  </Head>
  ,document.querySelector('#root'));
```

[image]